# VB.net Interract with a website (without WebBrowser)

Tags: vb.net, http, post, request

I would like to know if it is possible to interract with this website, without webbrowser:
https://msoos.github.io/cryptominisat_web

I would like to fill the editor element with a string, "press" run, and get the text from the output element

I tried that without success :

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://msoos.github.io/cryptominisat_web/")
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim requeststream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    requeststream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    requeststream.Close()

    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    TextBoxMain.Text = thepage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular Web app does its work client-side in JavaScript. There's no server to send text to. If you don't want to use a browser, then you'll need to use a standalone JavaScript interpreter (like V8 or SpiderMonkey) and set it up manually against the relevant bits of the page's JavaScript.

Comment: That's what i was afraid of.
And what if I use a WebBrowser ? Can I automatically set my text then ?